# Where should #include statements reside?

Tags: c++, include, methodology

As a returning newbie to C++, I'm trying to sort the #include methodology.

I'm following a certain set of guidelines I detail below the following example. So far this has worked out for me (the entire project keeps compiling :) ), but I'm worried I may encounter problems in the future, therefore my questions are - **is this a correct methodology? Is there a better one? What's the underlying logic that explains it?**

Consider the following example:

**Father.h**

```
#pragma once
class Father
{
    // Some implementation
};
```

**ClassA.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Father.h"
#include "StructC.h"
class ClassB;
class ClassA : public Father
{
    StructC struct_c_obj;
    ClassB class_b_obj;
    // Some implementation
};
```

**ClassA.cpp**

```
#include "Father.h"
#include "ClassB.h"
#include "StructC.h"
// Some implementation
```

**ClassB.h** and **ClassB.cpp**
 A class without includes

**StructC.h**

```
struct StructC {
    // Some implementation
};
```

I follow these guidelines:

- All *.h are headed by a `#pragma once` declaration
- If ClassA inherits from class Father, it must include it in both *.h and *.cpp file
- If ClassA uses ClassB (and has a ClassB variable declared at the class's scope), it has a `class ClassB;` decleration in ClassA.h and an `#include "ClassB.h"` in ClassA.cpp
- If ClassA uses StructC (and has a StructC variable declared at the class's scope), it has to include it in both ClassA.h and ClassA.cpp
- If ClassA uses ClassD or StructE but only in the ClassA.cpp file, then it should include them only there

This is probably a clumsy set of guidelines with little understanding of the underlying logic, so I'm probably going to get some wrath... Bring it on, I ***am*** trying to learn here... :)

**UPDATES:**

- As some have written below, I have an error in the example - you can use a forward declaration of ClassB in ClassA only if ClassA has a pointer or a reference to ClassB and not if it has a simple ClassB data-member.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are the guidelines I personally follow :

- Prefer forward declarations instead of includes whenever possible. In your case, `ClassA` contains a `ClassB` so a `#include "ClassB.h"` is required. Had the `ClassB` type only appear in the file by pointer or reference, a forward reference would have been sufficient
- Make header file "self sufficient" : compilation should never depend on the order of inclusions, and an include file should include / forward declare all it needs to be parsed
- To ensure that the preceding guideline is respected, always include `ClassA.h` first in `ClassA.cpp`, and use an arbitrary ordering for the following includes (I'm using alphabetical sort)

Regarding other aspects :

- `#pragma` is non standard, prefer [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)
- Keep in mind that you should never forward declare standard types : if `std::string` appears in your header file, you *have* to `#include <string>`
- If you end up with a header file which includes a million other files, you might want to look into the [pimpl idiom](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill04.htm) to reduce dependencies (this article also contains several other guidelines regarding header files).

Comment: I have two question regarding to your answer: 1) why we should prefer forward declarations ? 2)I am trying to understand why not to use #pragma, why it is important that this isn't in the standart?

Comment: 1) Because it reduces coupling (any file which includes a header, directly or indirectly, must be recompiled when the header changes)
2) Because you might want to port your code to another compiler someday

Comment: +1. This is a good answer. I would add that the order of includes is: `ClassA.h` first, then any `ClassB.h` or other classes of your own, then Boost headers or other library headers, and finally the standard library headers (`string`, `vector`, etc). Following that order helps ensure your own headers are self-sufficient.

Comment: Oh, another thing. You should almost never include complete class definitions in your header files. Only include forward declaration headers in your header files.

Comment: @Daniel: amusing, I personally use the reverse order. Since I include "ClassA.h" first in ClassA.cpp, I know it's self-sufficient, therefore I then include first std, then boost, then 3rd party, then middleware components, then other components of my own, and finally headers from this component. This is to prioritize the order in which things are declared, if there is a conflict between a header of the STL and a header of mine, the STL just cannot be changed :)

Comment: @Matthieu: The motive behind my reasoning is that including STL last means no header of mine can get something "for free". I also normally place my stuff in a namespace and usually always qualify std namespace. Helps keep things separate, even if some name is used twice (like vector).

Comment: @Daniel: I do the same for namespace and qualification, never felt too comfortable with the `using` though I use namespace aliasing when necessary. As I said for the headers, since my headers are checked in their own source file, I see no reason to check them once again in the others. But I don't really think it matters either.

Answer (score 1):

`#pragma once` is non-standard (but widely supported), so you may/may not want to use `#ifdef` guards instead.

As for whether you need to `#include` any particular header, it depends. If the code only requires a forward declaration, by all means avoid the import by just forward declaring the type.

And with the exception of template stuff, I think it is probably not-too-pretty to place long function definitions in the header files.

Having said that, I think that `ClassA.h` should actually include `ClassB.h` because any user of `ClassA.h` (presumably to use `ClassA`) will have to have `ClassB.h`. Well, if it is doing anything like allocating it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use forward declaration of ClassB, when ClassA has a data member of this type.
It's OK to use it, when it has a pointers to ClassB, as in:

```
#pragma once 
#include "Father.h" 
#include "StructC.h" 
class ClassB; 
class ClassA : public Father 
{ 
    StructC struct_c_obj; 
    ClassB *class_b_obj; 
    // Some implementation 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I've garnered from Python (because it's an absolute requirement there) is "import (include) it in the modules where you use it". This will keep you out of trouble when it comes to having or not having the definitions around.

Answer (score 0):

I usually don't use `pragma once` because pragmas are not standad. You could have to port your code to a different compiler where it's not defined, and you'd have to rewrite each with `#ifndef ... #define` idiom.

This is because I go straight with `#ifndef ... #define`.

Second thing: using many includes in an header file is not a good idea: I always try to minimize them. If you got too much of them, each time you change a little thing in one of them you'll have to recompile each dependent .cpp file.

If that's the case, I adopt the *Pimpl* idiom, that you can find described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) (see the C++ example). Anyway, if the project's size is not that big, I think that your approach is correct.